# Beautiful Soup web scraping and working with integers

Tags: python, types, beautifulsoup, casting

I have the following code, using BeautifulSoup and Python to webscrape (and subsequently work out a percentage) pertaining to some coronavirus stats:

```
url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
req = requests.get(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
data = bsObj.find_all("div",class_ = "maincounter-number")
    
totalcases=data[0].text.strip()
recovered=data[2].text.strip()
print(totalcases+3)

percentagerecovered=recovered/totalcases*100
```

The issue I am having is in producing the required value for the variable percentagerecovered.

I want to be working with integers, but the above didn't work, so I tried:

```
percentagecovered=int(recovered)/int(totalcases)*100 but it gave this error:

  File "E:\webscraper\webscraper\webscraper.py", line 17, in <module>
    percentagerecovered=int(recovered)/int(totalcases)*100
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6,175,537'
```

However, when I removed the casting, and tried to just print to see the value it gave a different error, that I am struggling to understand.

I changed it to:

```
totalcases=data[0].text.strip()
recovered=data[2].text.strip()
print(totalcases+3)

percentagerecovered=recovered/totalcases*100
```

**ERROR**

```
File "webscraper.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(totalcases+3)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I simply want to obtain those strings using the split method and then work with them assuming they are integers.

Currently, when I pass them (without casting) it doesn't display anything on the page...but when I do cast turning them into int, i get errors. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried:

```
totalcases=int(totalcases)
recovered=int(recovered)
```

**but this produced a further error:**

```
File "webscraper.py", line 17, in <module>
    totalcases=int(totalcases)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11,018,642'
```

I also tried this: (stripping the comma) as suggested below in the comments:

```
totalcases=data[0].text.strip()
recovered=data[2].text.strip()
totalcases=totalcases.strip(",")
totalcases=int(totalcases)
recovered=recovered.strip(",")
recovered=int(recovered)
percentagerecovered=recovered/totalcases*100
```

**ERROR:**

totalcases=int(totalcases)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11,018,684'

I note solutions like the function below (which I haven't tried) yet but they seem unnecessarily complex for what I'm trying to do. What is the best and easiest/most elegant solution.

**This seems along the right lines, but still produces an error:**

```
int(totalcases.replace(',', ''))
int(recovered.replace(',', ''))
```

**ERROR:**

```
File "webscraper.py", line 25, in <module>
    percentagerecovered=recovered/totalcases*100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: okay - thanks for the observation. But how do I work with it as an integer then?

Comment: you can strip comma & then try converting to integer, ``int("11,018,642".replace(",",""))``

Comment: I obviously can't use the number as it is being dynamically generated and held in the variable totalcases and also in recovered ...so I'd need to strip, not knowing the exact format.

Comment: Furthermore, if I tried totalcases=int(totalcases.replace(",","")) it would result in the error:  recovered=int(totalcases.replace(",",""))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: updated question above with what I've tried based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way to do it:

```
totalcases= int(data[0].text.strip().replace(',',''))
recovered = int(data[2].text.strip().replace(',',''))
```

Comment: You're a star - I think this it. But why didn't my approach, which seems similar, just on an extra line, work  (see last part of the question updated)

Comment: @MissComputing It's not clear from the edit exactly which version of `totalcases` caused the last error (you have several in the question).

Answer (score 2):

i wrote this little function that return to you a number, so you can increase it or do what ever you want

```
def str_to_int(text=None):
    if text == None:
        print('no text')
    else:
        text = text.split(',')
        num = int(''.join(text))
        return num
```

For example you have the number of totalcases: '11,018,642', so you do this:

```
totalcases = str_to_int('11,018,642')
```

Now you can do `totalcases*100` or anything else with it

Comment: will try this - but I am really looking,for teaching purposes, for the SIMPLEST way to do this. Why will int(totalcases.replace(',', ''))
int(recovered.replace(',', ''))
 not work?